# Why does mencoder output still images if I try to encode them under 3 FPS, while mencoder outputs dynamic images if I output them at 3 FPS or over?

Tags: mencoder

If I try...

```
mencoder mf://@NetSWLW12MA.txt -mf w=800:h=600:fps=1.5:type=png -ovc lavc     -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4:mbd=2:trell -oac copy -o NetSWLW12MA2.avi
```

I just get a bunch of still images of the first frame.

if I try...

```
mencoder mf://@NetSWLW12MA.txt -mf w=800:h=600:fps=4:type=png -ovc lavc     -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4:mbd=2:trell -oac copy -o NetSWLW12MA2.avi
```

then I get mencoder to robustly play all the images.

(there are 145 separate image frames contained in the txt file).

Is there a way to put all 145 images as separate images in the mencoder file when I encode it at 1 FPS?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem independently for MEncoder Redxii-SVN-r37239-4.8.3 and VitualDub 1.10.4. It seems a problem of the video file, not the software.
Maybe you could consider using the same image 3 times in a row with fps=3 to end up with an effective 1 fps movie.

Best regs

Andy